# Eurostat SDMX dataflow description python

Tags: python, sdmx

Using python I want to collect a list of all possible dataflows from Eurostat. I have the following code;

```
from pandasdmx import Request as rq
estat=rq('ESTAT')
cat_rsp=estat.get(resource_type='dataflow')
cat_msg=cat_rsp.msg
print [i.encode('utf-8') for i in cat_msg.dataflows]
```

this gives me a list of all possible resource_id's but I want also the descriptors. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Does `cat_msg` has the `descriptors` you want?

Comment: I don't think so, how can I check that?

Comment: No sorry,... 
Out[55]:
['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__doc__',
 '__format__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__module__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 '_elem',
 '_payload_names',
 '_reader',
 'dataflows',
 'header']

Answer (score 0):

Dataflow instances have a `description` attribute if that is what you're looking for.

```
print [i.description.en for i in cat_msg.dataflows]
```

Since Version 0.4 the preferred method is:

```
df = cat_rsp.write(columns=['name', 'description']).dataflow
```

This Returns a Pandas DataFrame that should contain descriptions on Dataflow instances.

Note that since version 0.4 the 'dataflows' Attribute of msg is deprecated in favor of 'dataflow'.

Leo